# Formatting Integers

Tags: python

I want to understand the logic behind the outputs of the below print statements.

```
x = 345
print ("%06d"%x)
print ("%-06d"%x)
```

The first statement would as expected prefix the number of zeroes required to make the total length as 6. The output is 000345 which I understand.

But the output of the second print statement is 345. How come? What is purpose of "-" operand?

Comment: `minus` mean align to left. You will see it when you add another element in print - ie. `print("%06d"%x, 'a')` `print("%-06d"%x, 'a')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`minus` means align to left.

You will see it when you add another element in print -

```
print("%06d"%x,  'a') 
print("%-06d"%x, 'a')
```

Result

```
000345 a
345    a
```

See: [PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: thanks @furas for the hyperlink and explanation, really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the minus and the leading zero specify conflicting requirements. Python arbitrarily picks the minus as the winner.